# The instrumental music during Midoriya's monologue on My Hero Academia season 3's prologue

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

Every episode starts with Midoriya's monologue,

> The prestigious school that turned out many heroes, UA high school
>
> enrolled in there hero course I continue to run towards my dreams... [...]

During this scene, there is an instrumental song that plays in the first 18 seconds of the show.

What is this instrumental song?

Answer (score 1):

This one is about the first 30 seconds of "Combat Liscense!".

It's the 5th song of disk 2 for the third OST (My Hero Academia 2018 Original Soundtrack)

Link to [Amazon MP3 JP](https://www.amazon.co.jp/%E3%80%8E%E5%83%95%E3%81%AE%E3%83%92%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%82%A2%E3%82%AB%E3%83%87%E3%83%9F%E3%82%A2%E3%80%8F2018-%E3%82%AA%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B8%E3%83%8A%E3%83%AB%E3%82%B5%E3%82%A6%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%E3%83%88%E3%83%A9%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF-%E6%9E%97-%E3%82%86%E3%81%86%E3%81%8D/dp/B07FCT9RDH/ref=sr_1_1_twi_mus_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1533713393&sr=8-1&keywords=My+hero+Acadamia+2018) for preview, proof and a possible where to buy.

Note: track is about half way down under the Kanji 戦闘許可!

Answer (score 0):

The instrumental is callled ''Battle of Deku''